# Python Pillow input image less weight than final, how?

Tags: python, image

So I'm trying to optimize some images with `Pillow` using `Python`, but the original image is actually more optimized than final image... How can this happen?

This is the simplest script I'm using, there are others, which crop the image, remove whitespace and some stuff that might reduce file size, but it gets bigger...

So I tried only the optimizing part, just opened the image then saved it to JPEG with 80 quality.

Original image is `29,7KB` final image is `31,5KB`. How is this possible?

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()

image = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imagen))

ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = max(image.size) ** 2
image.save(output, 'JPEG', quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)

contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()
return contents
```

Comment: If the image was a JPEG (or any lossy format), this can occur as compression artifacts can't easily be compressed.

Comment: How was the original image saved? What app generated it, what compression number was used, is it progressive?

Comment: The images are always JPEG files, I don't know if they were compressed or not, but maybe what @DanD. is saying is what is happening, I've tried other  sources where images are bigger (may be not pre-compressed?) and script works correctly...

Comment: The old file could already have been saved at a lower quality. Saving at a higher quality will still use more data.